# Using the new api and tool interface in hadoop(2.2.0)

Tags: java, api, hadoop

(I'm sure this was asked a couple of times, however this is such a general "fuzzy" question, and the hadoop api itself and version numbers are so confusing I feel all my google searches are actually useless. So I'm sorry if this is trivial)

I've been trying to use the new tool interface for running jobs in hadoop. I've been told as a general rule, that if I use the new api I should steer away from using the org.apache.hadoop.mapred and use only the classes in the 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce' package.

However, when looking in the code example in new api documentation under [tool](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html):

```
   public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
     // Configuration processed by ToolRunner
     Configuration conf = getConf();

     // Create a JobConf using the processed conf
     JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MyApp.class);

     // Process custom command-line options
     Path in = new Path(args[1]);
     Path out = new Path(args[2]);

     // Specify various job-specific parameters     
     job.setJobName("my-app");
     job.setInputPath(in);
     job.setOutputPath(out);
     job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
     job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

     // Submit the job, then poll for progress until the job is complete
     JobClient.runJob(job);
     return 0;
   }
```

it's seems they use the JobConf class from the older api, and this also generates errors for me. specifically I get

> The method setPartitionerClass(Class) in the type JobConf is not applicable for the arguments

and other errors accordingly when trying to set my map, reduce, combiner classes.

Using the 'Job' class from the new api works for me, but all it's constructors are marked deprecated. What is the correct way to do this?

This gets even more ugly when trying to use the JobControl class from the **new** api, which for some reason [wants to use the "Job" class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/JobControl.html#addJob%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job%29) from the **old** api. and again using the job class from the old api requires me to use the old JobConf class as well. I feel there is something very basic I miss here.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the 'Job' class from the new api works for me, but all it's constructors are marked deprecated. What is the correct way to do this?

A non-deprecated way to get the job in the new API is...

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration());
```

---

> This gets even more ugly when trying to use the JobControl class from the new api, which for some reason wants to use the "Job" class from the old api. and again using the job class from the old api requires me to use the old JobConf class as well.

It's always a bit confusing when new API's are designed with backwards compatibility in mind.

```
JobControl.addJob(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job)
```

takes the old job as the input,

```
JobControl.addJob(new ControlledJob(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job, ...))
```

takes the new job as the input.